# Add ability to add a short phrase to Hats

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, winter-bash-2016

I read a short while ago today, that someone was looking for an update to add to hats. Can't find that to post to it so I am making suggestion here.

How about something like up to a 3 word phrase to add to hats. Like "Yippie" or "Party Like 1999" (I know not great examples.) but something like a hover that pop ups a balloon of the phrase that the hat wearer can enter.

Comment: Though wearing hats, we still hate fun (like that)!

Comment: Can all hats say what panta wrote? :D

Comment: That's the spirit! When things don't go your way, insult people who disagree with you!

Comment: On meta, downvotes mean disagreement. Peiple don'tfeel your suggestion to be worthwhile. The 'be nice' policy still applies. Also what Mike said. You will never get a good reception (especially not on meta) by insulting those disagreeing.

Comment: It wasn't an insult, simply a reference to being a "Party Pooper", this was suppose to be fun. Sorry for the poor choice of words then. It would be nice to see if there had been any up votes instead of tally. Even if it was 26 - 0. Of course if I made the suggestion to show both vote types, why do I feel that would get voted down too! Got to love the holiday spirit!!

Comment: @htm11h on the desktop site, you can see the vote split by clicking on the score. Currently this question has +3 / -31

Comment: I think you need 1000 experience to see that split count.

Comment: You could edit your avatar and add the text to it. It won't be in a hover pop up balloon, but since I don't think people typically hover over avatars (especially on touch devices!) having it statically in the image itself would let everyone see it.

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate your enthusiasm with hats, <strike>everyone</strike> most people love them.  I'm not sure why we'd need to have users add a short phrase to the hats. Considering that hat season is temporary fun at the end of each year, it seems like a lot of work with not a lot of benefits, so unfortunately this is [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

Comment: Its wasn't so much of a need as it was a suggestion to what I thought was developer looking for ideas to enhance the hat feature. Just can't seem to find that link.

Comment: And by the way, why the decline tag? If I recall, aren't there something like 300 or 400 thousand users on this site? Can't we hold out for the electoral? 27 seems a bit light.

Comment: @htm11h Well as an employee of Stack Exchange I saying it's not going to happen. Hats is a temporary event not a permanent feature to the site, and I don't see a benefit to it.

Comment: That's the spirit!! Not a permanent feature? Isn't this like the 3rd or 4th year running? Too bad, it is a cool seasonal break from it all!!

Comment: Considering it runs for 3 out of 52 weeks, it's not permanent @htm11h